# Are there conlangs designed to be whispered?

Tags: phonology, list-of-languages, unnatural-features

We all know that natural languages can be whispered and we use whispering for several purposes, e.g., to avoid someone unwanted listening, or in order not to disturb a larger audience. But are there conlangs that are designed to whispered and don't have a "fully voiced" form?

I am aware of [Dritok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dritok) and I'd like to hear from more of them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

The [Whispering Language](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/8hltug/the_whispering_language/) is designed for communicating with deaf-mutes -- a language that can easily be lipread.

[Ahtialan](https://conlang.fandom.com/wiki/Ahtialan) came to be used as a whisper language.

[Xylphika](http://skyknowledge.com/xylphika.htm) only rarely demonstrates voicing.

[Parseltongue](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Parseltongue) seems to be compounded of sibilants and voiceless vowels.